# prove a map is homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y \subset C[0,1]$. $\,$ Suppose $C[0,1]$ has the $L_1$- or $L_\infty$ topology, then the natural map $p(a,b,c)=a+bt+ct^2: \mathbb{R}^3_\text{usual} \to Y$ is a homeomorphism.

I need to prove $p$ is invertible and both $p$ and $p^{-1}$ are continuous. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $p:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow Y:(a,b,c)\mapsto p(a,b,c)$ where $(p(a,b,c))(t)=a+bt+ct^2$? And what is $Y$? How do we know that $\text{im}(p)\subset Y$? I don't quite understand your notation.

Comment: sorry that $Y \subset C[0,1]$ be polynomials of degree $\leq 2$

Answer (score 1):

$p:\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow Y$ is a linear isomorphism (for injectivity, the kernel is...). The norm in $Y$ is irrelevant because because in finite dimension all the norms are equivalent. Finally, in finite dimension all the linear functions are continuous.